# Calculating based on input fields in PHP

Tags: php

I want to have 2 input fields and a button. Once you press the button it adds the two numbers together and shows the result below. The input numbers have to be between 0 and 10. If one of the inputs is 0, the sum has to be 0 no matter what.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Enter Num1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="num1" /><br>
    <label>Enter Num2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="num2" /><br><br>
    <input  type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Add">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
    {
        $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
        $num2 = $_POST['num2'];

        $total =  $num1+$num2;

        echo "The total value is: ".$total;
    }
?>
```

The first problem is that when I press the 'Add' button, my input fields are cleared and nothing happens. The second problem is that I have no clue on how to add the 2 mentioned conditions. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: try out (int) $num1 + (int)$num2

Answer (score 1):

> The first problem is that when I press the 'Add' button, my input fields are cleared and nothing happens

This how it works. If you want your `<input>`s to be pre-filled with any values, you must do that yourself. There's `value` argument for any `<input>` you can use.

> The second problem is that I have no clue on how to add the 2 mentioned conditions.

there's no additional conditions clear in your question. You just added two values in proper way, so it's unclear what you are having problem with here.

Comment: But why doesn't the result show up when I press the 'Add' button?